# POSIXlt timezone conversion

Tags: r, datetime

I want to plot an histogram of a time series. The original time zone is UTC but I want to plot the histogram in a different time zone.

Please consider the following

```
data = c("2013-11-01 05:43:04", "2013-11-01 12:59:03","2013-11-01 21:06:3","2013-11-01 21:11:08")

time <- as.POSIXlt(data, tz = "UTC")

hist(time,"hours")

hist(as.POSIXlt(time,tz="Australia/Sydney"),"hours")
```

It seems that `as.POSIXlt(time,tz="Australia/Sydney")`doesn't change the output but simply redefine the internal 'tz' of the object. Is this correct? How could I plot the histogram in a different time zone?

Answer (score 0):

Use `as.POSIXct` to convert `time` in the `as.POSIXlt` call:

```
hist(as.POSIXlt(as.POSIXct(time),tz="Australia/Sydney"),"hours")
```